# How to create list of list

Tags: prolog

I having a problem with predicate which creates list of list for example

```
?-listoflist([p v q, p, r], R).
R=[ [p,q],[p],[r] ]
```

So far i have:

```
:- op(500, xfy, v).

listoflist([],[]):-!.
listoflist([H], [[H]]):-!
listoflist([H|T], [Result]):-
        change_to_list(H,Tmp),
        listoflist(T, [Tmp|Result])..

change_to_list(X v Y, [X|List]):-
     change_to_list(Y,List),!.
change_to_list(X,[X]).
```

Answer (score 2):

For operator declarations, always look what Prolog already has and fit your own operators into it:

```
?- current_op(Pri,Fix,\/).
   Pri = 500, Fix = yfx.
```

A left-associative operator makes much more sense here. Maybe you can reuse this, instead of defining your own? And in case you want your own, take **the very same** priorities.

```
:- op(500, yfx, v).

operands(Op) --> [Op], {functor(Op,Op,0)}.
operands(L v R) --> operands(L), operands(R).

expr_operands(Expr, Ops) :-
   phrase(operands(Expr), Ops).

?- maplist(expr_operands, [p v q, p, r], R).
   R = [[p,q],[p],[r]].
```

Comment: I rly want take my own operator. Could u help me write predicate witch use mine?

Answer (score 0):

Your `listoflists/2` should be simpler and doesn't need cuts:

```
listoflists([], []).
listoflists([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    change_to_list(X, Y),
    listoflists(Xs, Ys).
```

The other predicate, `change_to_list/2` seems fine to me.

Notice how you collect the results *in the head of the clause*, not in the recursive call!